# Need SQL statement rewritten to provide accurate results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am only getting one row returned with this query, and I should have one row of results per user id: The ul.logins records a datestamp every time a user logs in, so there are multiple entries, but I am only trying to get the "most recent time", hence the max function.

```
select u.user_id "User ID", ifnull(max(ul.logins),'Never logged in') "Last Login"
from users u
join user_logins ul on u.id = ul.user_id
where u.user_id in ('leonarddicaprio','tomhanks','tomcruise','juliaroberts');
```

Comment: add a `group by u.user_id` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` is an aggregate function which returns only 1 row - *unless used by `group by`*.

By having `max(ul.logins)`, you're only asking for one row - The one with the highest `logins` value. Group your results by `user_id` for it to give the max value per user.